# Am I leaking images in supabase's S3 bucket?

Tags: flutter, supabase, supabase-database

Im trying to wrap my head around avatar management for supabase users. I have followed the user management starter and think I understand how it all kind of works. I am still confused and baffled about a few things which I hope you guys can clear up for me. I am working in flutter btw.

1. If you make the function delete_storage_object (and the other [functions](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-react?database-method=sql#storage-management)) in the public table isn't this accessible for every role by default? I manually revoked access for all the functions from the tutorial so that only the postgress role can execute them when triggered.
2. When the user uploads a picture but for example the updateProfile call goes wrong, wouldn't that mean I have an orphan file that just got uploaded? How would I prevent this?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Of the second point what im also worried about is abuse by malicious users. If they read the endpoints and send a bunch of random images they make a lot of "orphans" which we have to pay for.